# Witty functional equation

Tags: summation, contest-math

> Let
>   $$f(x) = 2/(4^x + 2)$$
>   for real numbers $x$. Evaluate
>   $$f(1/2001) + f(2/2001) + f(3/2001) + \cdots + f(2001/2001)$$

Any idea?

Comment: But this is not a functional equation...

Comment: @Ruslan: You are referring to the narrow sense. However, as mathematics becomes more advanced, the more it tends to follow the conventions of ordinary language. In particular, ordinary language commonly uses a range of meaning from very narrow to very wide. It could be argued that this IS a functional equation in the wide sense, that is, a function defined by an equation, where there is some unsettled or unresolved issue concerning the expression that defines the function.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle f(1-x)=\frac{2}{4^{1-x}+2}=\frac{2\cdot 4^x}{4+2\cdot 4^x}=\frac{4^x}{2+ 4^x}$

$\displaystyle f(x)+f(1-x)=\frac{2}{4^x+2}+\frac{4^x}{2+ 4^x}=1$

The required sum is

$$\frac{2000}{2}\times 1+f(1)=1000+\frac{2}{4+2}=\frac{3001}{3}$$

Comment: nice solution +1)